# Get all key-value pair from nested JSON array

Tags: java, json, selenium

Hi I have a nested JSON which has JSON array also. i need all single key-value pairs.
below is the nested JSON which has some JSON arrays.

```
{
  "relatedquoteresponse":{
    "responsepreamble":{
      "responseStatus":"Passed",
      "statusCode":"200"
    },
    "phone":null,
    "symbol":"$",
    "retrieverelatedquotes":[
      {
        "quoteId":23232
      },
      {
        "quoteName":"Netally-Service"
      }
    ],
    "CheckStatus":{
      "StatusCode":200,
      "responseMessage":"Found"
    }
  }
}
```

I need an output like this:

```
responseStatus : "Passed"
statusCode : "200"
Phone: null
symbol: "$"
quoteID: 23232
quoteName: "Netally-Service"
```

I tried below code, but getting this output.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
    Iterator<String> iterator = jsonNode.fieldNames();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next();
        printRec(jsonNode, key);
    }

public static void printRec(JsonNode jsonNode, String key) {
        JsonNode node = jsonNode.get(key);
        if (node.isObject()) {
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = node.fields();
            fields.forEachRemaining(field -> {
                printRec(node, field.getKey());
                if (!field.getValue().isObject()) {
                    System.out.println(field.getKey() + " : " + field.getValue());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

OutPut:

```
responseStatus : "Passed"
statusCode : "200"
Phone: null
symbol: "$"
retrieverelatedquotes : [{"quoteId":23232},{"quoteName":"Netally-Service"}]
```

Can anyone help me on this to get all key-value pairs not in array like above.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion really helps, even works for multiple levels.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
printRec(jsonNode, "");

----------

public static void printRec(JsonNode jsonNode, String key) {
    if (jsonNode.isValueNode()) {
        System.out.println(key + " : " + jsonNode);
    } else if (jsonNode.isObject()) {
        jsonNode.fields().forEachRemaining(field -> printRec(field.getValue(), field.getKey()));
    } else if (jsonNode.isArray()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonNode.size(); i++) {
            printRec(jsonNode.get(i), key + "[" + i + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
responseStatus : "Passed"
statusCode : "200"
phone : null
symbol : "$"
quoteId : 23232
quoteName : "Netally-Service"
StatusCode : 200
responseMessage : "Found"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex named groups feature to get all single keys and values

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.+)\":(?![{\\[])(.+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " : " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Output will be:

```
responseStatus : "Passed",
statusCode : "200"
phone : null,
symbol : "$",
quoteId : 23232
quoteName : "Netally-Service"
StatusCode : 200,
responseMessage : "Found"
```

You can easily modify the pattern to get all single keys with int value for example or null value

Simple article about [Regex Named groups and Backreferences](https://amrdeveloper.medium.com/android-regex-named-groups-and-backreferences-940cb7f545b1)

Comment: Hi Amr, It really helps me a lot. i need to learn this regex. can you paste any other reference link here.

Comment: Thats great bro, Try this site while you are learning it will give you description your regex and you can learn more https://regex101.com/

Comment: There are literally entire libraries built to read JSON... why would you use regex to parse it? Raymond Choi's answer is the right one.

Comment: @JeffC You can solve one problem in many different ways, the best solution depend on your project